# Forward slash in column name throwing an incorrect syntax "/"

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-metamodel

I am trying to execute insert query using Apache meta model on a sql server database - Where insert query contains a column name with forward slash(/) in it such as 'col4a/col4b' and query will be created by metamodel as

`INSERT INTO dbo."table1" (col1,"col2 Type",col3,col4a/col4b) VALUES ('value1','value2','value3','value4')`

When I execute this statement the code throws an error `incorrect syntax near '/'`.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to escape special character like / in my column name.

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to handle poorly named columns in sql server is with square brackets [ ].

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 
(
    col1
    , [col2 Type]
    , col3
    , [col4a/col4b]
) 
VALUES 
(
    'value1'
    , 'value2'
    , 'value3'
    , 'value4'
)
```

Comment: SQL Standard double quotes usually also work with SQL Server (might require an option to be enabled).

Comment: I have already tried it, it works fine in sql server ui but I can't implement via code because apache metamodel doesn't identify column and gives an error as [col2 Type] - no such column in table.

Comment: Is it possible to rename your columns? Spaces and other characters really shouldn't be used in column names.

Comment: No because it will effect on other objects related to that column like(procedures, triggers, functions).